# Loading RAW grayscale image with FreeImage

Tags: c++, freeimage

How can I load RAW 16-bit grayscale image with FreeImage?

I have `unsigned char*` buffer with raw data. I know its dimensions in pixels  and I know it is 16bit grayscale.

I'm trying to load it with

```
FIBITMAP* bmp = FreeImage_ConvertFromRawBits(buffer, 1000, 1506, 2000, 16, 0, 0, 0);
```

and get broken RGB888 image. It is unclear what color masks I should use for grayscale as it has only one channel.

Comment: Your graphic file is it 16bit per channel? Meaning that its 16bits for r, g & b respectively?

Comment: Pass the same mask to all 3: 0xFFFF (since it is grayscale, all channels have the same values).

Comment: Here's a discussion that is of similar nature; this might help: https://sourceforge.net/p/freeimage/discussion/36109/thread/762e5b76/

Answer (score 2):

After many experiments I found partially working solution with `FreeImage_ConvertFromRawBitsEx`:

```
FIBITMAP* bmp = FreeImage_ConvertFromRawBitsEx(true, buffer, FIT_UINT16, 1000, 1506, 2000, 16, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF);
```

(thanks @1201ProgramAlarm for hint with masks).

In this way, FreeImage loads the data, but in some semi-custom format. Most of conversion and saving functions (tried: JPG, PNG, BMP, TIF) fail.

As I can't load data in native 16bit format, I preferred to convert it into 8bit grayscale

```
unsigned short* buffer = new unsigned short[1000 * 1506];

// load data

unsigned char* buffer2 = new unsigned char[1000 * 1506];
for (int i = 0; i < 1000 * 1506; i++)
  buffer2[i] = (unsigned char)(buffer[i] / 256.f);

FIBITMAP* bmp = FreeImage_ConvertFromRawBits(buffer2, 1000, 1506, 1000, 8, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, true);
```

This is really not the best solution, I even don't want to mark it as right answer (will wait for something better). But after this the format will be convenient for FreeImage and it could save/convert data to whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Concerning your issue: I have read this from their PDF documentation [FreeImage1370.pdf](https://mirrors.dotsrc.org/exherbo/FreeImage3170.pdf):

---

> ### FreeImage_ConvertFromRawBits
>
> #### `1 4 8 16 24 32`
>
> ---
>
> DLL_API FIBITMAP *DLL_CALLCONV FreeImage_ConvertFromRawBits(BYTE *bits, int width, int
>   height, int pitch, unsigned bpp, unsigned red_mask, unsigned green_mask, unsigned
>   blue_mask, BOOL topdown FI_DEFAULT(FALSE));
>
> ---
>
> Converts a raw bitmap somewhere in memory to a FIBITMAP. The parameters in this
>   function are used to describe the raw bitmap. The first parameter is a pointer to the start of
>   the raw bits. The width and height parameter describe the size of the bitmap. The pitch
>   defines the total width of a scanline in the source bitmap, including padding bytes that may be
>   applied. The bpp parameter tells FreeImage what the bit depth of the bitmap is. The
>   red_mask, green_mask and blue_mask parameters tell FreeImage the bit-layout of the color
>   components in the bitmap. The last parameter, topdown, will store the bitmap top-left pixel
>   first when it is TRUE or bottom-left pixel first when it is FALSE.
>
> - When the source bitmap uses a 32-bit padding, you can calculate the pitch using the
>     following formula:
>     int pitch = ((((bpp * width) + 31) / 32) * 4);

---

In the code you are showing:

> ```
> FIBITMAP* bmp = FreeImage_ConvertFromRawBits(buffer, 1000, 1506, 2000, 16, 0, 0, 0);
> ```

You have the appropriate `FIBTMAP*` return type, you pass in your `buffer` of `raw bits`. From there the 2<sup>nd</sup> & 3<sup>rd</sup> parameters which are the `width` & `height`: `width = 1000`, `height = 1506` and the 4<sup>th</sup> parameter which is the `pitch`: `pitch = 2000` (if the bitmap is using 32bit padding refer to the last note above), the 5<sup>th</sup> parameter will be the bit depth measured in `bpp` you have as `bpp = 16`, the next 3 parameters are for your `RGB color masks`. Here you label them all as being `0`. The last parameter is a bool flag for the `orientation` of the `image` :

> ```
>   if (topdown == true ) { 
>       stores top-left pixel first ) 
>   else { 
>       bottom left pixel is stored first 
>   }
> ```

in which you omit the value.

Without more code of how you are reading in the file, parsing the header information etc. to prepare your `buffer` it is hard to tell where else there may be an error or an issue, but from what you provided; I think you need to check the `color channel masks` for `grayscale images`.

---

**EDIT** - I found another PDF for FreeImage from standford.edu [here](http://graphics.stanford.edu/courses/cs148-10-summer/docs/FreeImage3131.pdf) that refers to an older version `3.13.1` however the function declaration - definition doesn't look like it has changed any and they provide examples for b `FreeImage_ConvertToRawBits` & `Free_Image_ConvertFromRawBits`:

> ```
> // this code assumes there is a bitmap loaded and
> // present in a variable called ‘dib’
> // convert a bitmap to a 32-bit raw buffer (top-left pixel first)
> // --------------------------------------------------------------
> FIBITMAP *src = FreeImage_ConvertTo32Bits(dib);
> FreeImage_Unload(dib);
> // Allocate a raw buffer
> int width = FreeImage_GetWidth(src);
> int height = FreeImage_GetHeight(src);
> int scan_width = FreeImage_GetPitch(src);
> BYTE *bits = (BYTE*)malloc(height * scan_width);
> // convert the bitmap to raw bits (top-left pixel first)
> FreeImage_ConvertToRawBits(bits, src, scan_width, 32,
> FI_RGBA_RED_MASK, FI_RGBA_GREEN_MASK, FI_RGBA_BLUE_MASK,
> TRUE);
> FreeImage_Unload(src);
> // convert a 32-bit raw buffer (top-left pixel first) to a FIBITMAP
> // ----------------------------------------------------------------
> FIBITMAP *dst = FreeImage_ConvertFromRawBits(bits, width, height, scan_width,
> 32, FI_RGBA_RED_MASK, FI_RGBA_GREEN_MASK, FI_RGBA_BLUE_MASK, FALSE);
> ```

---

I think this should help you with your question about the `bit masks` for the color channels in a grayscale image.

Comment: I have read this PDF too and I still have no answer of what I should pass as mask. There is no loading and parsing of header. I just have a buffer and I know the kind of data. It is in form of unsigned short[]. Each value is pixel in 16bit grayscale

Comment: @rattler I edited my answer with a little more information.

Comment: See your edit. Yes, it is correct handling for *color* images. But my problem was a grayscale.

Answer (score 0):

You already mentioned the `FreeImage_ConvertFromRawBitsEx()` function, which was added at some point between FreeImage v3.8 and v3.17, but are you calling it correctly? I was able to use this function with 16-bit grayscale data:

```
int nBytesPerRow = nWidth * 2;
int nBitsPerPixel = 16;
FIBITMAP* pFIB = FreeImage_ConvertFromRawBitsEx(TRUE, pImageData, FIT_UINT16, nWidth, nHeight, nBytesPerRow, nBitsPerPixel, 0, 0, 0, TRUE);
```

Note that `nBytesPerRow` and `nBitsPerPixel` have to be specified correctly for the 16-bit data. Also, I believe the color mask parameters are irrelevant for this data, since it is monochrome.

EDIT: I noticed that you said that saving the 16-bit data did not work correctly.  That may be due to the file formats themselves. The only file format that I have found to be compatible with 16-bit grayscale data is TIFF. So, if you have 16-bit grayscale data, you can save a TIFF with `FreeImage_Save()` but you cannot save a BMP.